# how to get data from a sql table to a website

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am trying to create a form in website and display the contents in another website. how do I retrieve data from a sql table a and add it to the website. which is better to use php or js

I tried using JS but its not working like I want it to

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, following this [How to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting question. A shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have to involve php. Js cannot talk directly to your database

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve data from an SQL table and display it on a website, you can use either PHP or JavaScript, but they serve different purposes in this context.
PHP is a server-side scripting language, and it is commonly used for server-side operations like interacting with databases.
You can use PHP to connect to your database, retrieve data from the SQL table, and then generate HTML to display that data on your website.